# How to make the cases bracket in an equation more elegant?

Tags: equations, cases

I am writing an equation containing cases using the following codes:

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta A = 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{\pi \left( 1-\mu \right) d_i^2}{42GW_c} & \text{if } a = 0\\
        0                                  & \text{if } a = 1
    \end{cases}                                                                                                 
\end{equation}
```

It worked fine but the output is not beautiful, I want to make the left brace smaller, could someone tell me how to deal with it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos, I am using the elsevier  double column template, should I attach the whole template files?

Comment: No, just MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document, which produce showed equation. "Elegancy" of your bracket depends on used font ... and its very opinion based. To me looks fine, will be nicer if it will a bit less tall.

Comment: If you use `cas-dc` documentclass, then you should write into the first line the next: `\PassOptionsToPackage{nomath}{stix}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the brace obtained with `empheq` will be more like you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={\Delta A =\empheqlbrace}]{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
      &\frac{\pi \left( 1-\mu \right) d_i^2}{42GW_c} & & \text{if } a = 0\\[1ex]
      & 0 & & \text{if } a = 1
  \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The output by the conventional `cases` looks good, but it is possible to do this with `tikz` and `nicematrix` to provide flexibility in adjusting the braces thickness to your taste.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\tikzset{
    BraceMirrored/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt,
            pre =moveto, pre  length=1.1pt,
            post=moveto, post length=1.1pt,
            mirror,
            raise=#1},
        thick,
        pen colour=black},
        BraceMirrored/.default=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}
        \Delta A = \mspace{11mu}
        \begin{NiceArray}{@{}l @{\quad}l}[cell-space-limits=1.1pt]
            \frac{\pi \left( 1-\mu \right) d_i^2}{42GW_c} & \text{if $a = 0$}
        \\
            0 & \text{if $a = 1$} 
            \CodeAfter
            {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw[BraceMirrored={3.7pt}, thin] (1-1.north west) -- node[left=3.7pt] {} (2-1.south west); % change thickness by including `thin`, 'very thin', or 'ultra thin'
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what You need?

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta A = 
\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{\pi \left( 1-\mu \right) d_i^2}{42GW_c} & \text{if } a = 0\\
        0                                  & \text{if } a = 1
    \end{cases}                                        
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Elsevier's double column template, the `cas-dc` documentclass loads the `stix` package, which causes your problem. If you write `\PassOptionsToPackage{nomath}{stix}` into the first line of the source, this effect will be disappeared.